# Do function calls have a lifetime in rust, or only variables?

Tags: rust

Edit: This question was too complicated obviously. Here's a much simpler example that explains what I'm trying to ask:

```
#[feature(macro_rules)];    
macro_rules! trace(
  ($($arg:tt)*) => (
    { let x = ::std::io::stdout().write_line(format_args!(::std::fmt::format, $($arg)*)); println!("{}", x); }
  );
)

#[deriving(Show)]
struct Foo<T> {
  data: ~T
}

impl<T> Foo<T> {

  // Notice how the 'pontless_marker' variable is passed into this function for
  // no reason other than that it allows us to copy the lifetime scope of the
  // 'marker' variable in the test below, so the lifetime of the returned pointer
  // is valid for that block.
  fn returns_to_scope_with_marker<'a>(&'a self, pointless_marker:&'a int) -> &'a ~T {
    return &self.data;
  }

  // This doesn't work, but it should. You should be able to invoke this function
  // as something like: let marked = bar.returns_to_scope::<LIFETIME???>();
  /*
  fn returns_to_scope<'a>(& self) -> &'a ~T {
    return &self.data;
  }
  */
}

#[test]
fn test_lifetime_return_scope() {
  let bar = Foo { data: ~Foo { data: ~10 } };
  {
    let marker = 10;
    let marked = bar.returns_to_scope_with_marker(&marker);
    trace!("{:?}", marked);
  }
}
```

See the 'pointless_marker' in the example above.

This is what I want to avoid. If the function is also typed as blah<'a>, I feel like I should be able to explicitly invoke it using x.blah::<Something goes here>().

Is that just flat out impossible?

Comment: lifetime on self doesnt't mean it will have the same lifetime, it just means that it is valid up to a lifetime of self

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok here is the code that will hopefully solve your problems:

```
#[feature(macro_rules)];    
//Macro rules is unchanged

#[deriving(Show)]
struct Foo<'a, T> {
  data: &'a T
}

impl<'a, T> Foo<'a, T> {

  fn returns_to_scope(&'a self) -> &'a T {
    self.data
  }
}

fn main() {
  let bar = Foo { data: &Foo { data: &10 } };
  {
    let marked = bar.returns_to_scope();
    trace!("{:?}", marked);
  }
}
```

I'll go line by line (but not in order) and explain what was the problem and how to solve it.

First you said you wanted to avoid warnings and to avoid the pointless variable sent. I agree those parameters are unnecessary. To avoid adding variable to the function, and it's parameters a life time parameter will be added to the `impl` and the `struct` definitions, in following lines:

```
 struct Foo<'a, T> 
 ...
 impl<'a, T> Foo<'a, T> 
 // note: impl<'a,T> is mandatory, because we can say <'a, int> for example
 //       which is not what we want
```

`'a` is a lifetime param it acts as another generic type (i.e. `T`).

*If we have `'a` lifetime we kinda need to tie it to something... We'll return back to this part once `fn returns_to_scope` is fixed later on in the text, but it's obvious that data will get the lifetime since - it's the only value in the struct Foo and it is returned out of a function that requires something a lot like `&'a T`.

Now, we can look a bit better at the `fn returns_to_scope` function. If you look at your original function you almost had it right.

```
 fn returns_to_scope<'a>(& self) -> &'a ~T {
   return &self.data;
 }
```

*First thing that strikes me the wrong way is that you have a `&~` pointer (`&'a ~T`). Why? You do understand it's a stack pointer to a pointer that allocates on the heap? It's not really useful unless you are doing some pointer pointing acrobatics, but I assume it's a mistake. If it's not well, you can always make a `~T value` and borrow it.*

So you want your `returns_to_scope` to return a `self.data` field in some way, if you are returning a field that belongs to a struct Foo, I think it's more sensible to use same lifetime as the struct Foo, the field belongs to; So I changed the description to:

```
fn returns_to_scope(&self) -> &'a T
```

I omit the `<'a>` generic parameter because I don't need to generalize this function over `'a` lifetime, `'a` lifetime is part of the struct we get it for free by borrowing the struct. However I forgot to say which lifetime on `&self` so compiler will complain and I'll just change `&self` to be annotated with `'a` life time.

```
fn returns_to_scope(&'a self) -> &'a T
```

For the finishing touch, since Rust allows to return the field just by omitting `;` I can write:

```
fn returns_to_scope(&'a self) -> &'a T {
   self.data
}
```

Instead of `return self.data;`.

Now we see that our field in struct is a natural candidate for `'a` life time so

```
data: &'a T
```

is added to the struct Foo and all pieces are now in place.

Comment: This is a really great answer, but I thought I'd just point out to anyone else that finds it later that this *isnt* a lifetime scope on a function call; this is using the lifetime on the *struct instance* for the returned value. The effect is the same (since marked is only valid for the given block), but technically if you did: let marked; { marked = bar.foo(); } println!("{}", marked), the value would still be valid *outside* of the block scope where foo() was called.

Comment: Edit's are welcome ;) I hope someone more knowledgeable will come along and fix any issues in. I'm not sure what you refer by `this isnt a lifetime scope on a function call`?

Comment: Specifically, the 'a in returns_to_scope is the lifetime of the variable bar. returns_to_scope() doesn't have it's own lifetime b' which is the scope *in which* the call is made. For example, b' for some call foo() would be the entire block { ....; foo(); ...; ...; } in which foo() is invoked. I was just pointing out that isn't what is happening here~

Comment: Ah yes, you are quite correct, extracted function would be valid in the same block as `Foo` was defined, instead of just the place where `fn returns_to_scope_with_marker` if I understood your correctly.